# MATLAB: Access Data in Nested Structure using For loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, struct, nested, field

Good day,

I have a nested structure in this format.

```
Data: [1x1 struct]
    a: [1x1 struct]
        a1: [10x1 double]
        a2: [10x1 double]
        a3: [10x1 double]
    b: [1x1 struct]
        b1: [10x1 double]
        b2: [10x1 double]
    c: [1x1 struct]
        c1: [10x1 double]
        c2: [10x1 double]
        c3: [10x1 double]
        c4: [10x1 double]
```

Each of sub-fields of `a`, `b` & `c` are duration percentage of an event in buckets. The number of elements in each bucket are number of data-sets. I'd like sum the bucket values of each data set and discard the entire data-set if they don't add up to 100%. How may I access each element of the buckets for `a`, `b` & `c` fields of `Data` using for loop in a simply format.

**EDIT**: I figured out how to call the sub-fields & it's elements, sum the percentages & now, if the data-sets not adding up to 100 need to fully removed from each sub-field.

```
field = fieldnames(Data);
for group = 1:length(field)
    for subfield = fieldnames(Data.(field{group}))

        fieldSize = structfun(@(field) length(field),Data.(field{group}));
        nb_datasets = fieldSize(1,1);

        for jj = 1:nb_datasets
            for ii = 1:length(subfield)
                a_dataset_pcts(jj,ii) = Data.(field{group}).(subfield{ii})(jj,1);
            end
            a_pct_total(jj,:) = sum(a_dataset_pcts(jj,:));
        end

    end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Like replacing `@(field) length(field)` with `@(field) mean(field)`.

Comment: @Mad Physicist Re-iterting my question above: a1, a2, a3 are the percentage buckets for the group a. I'd like to know how to access each of these bucket elements so I could preform multiple tasks later on (mean value was just an example). The number of elements in the buckets are the number of datasets. The bucket elements represent percentages of an event and sum of a1(1,1), a2(1,1), a3(1,1) should add up to 100%. Other task which will follow up should be the removal of the entire dataset if they do not add up to 100%.

Comment: I understood the question. What have you tried to solve it. You know that a `for` loop is a possible solution. Could we see the `for` loop that you tried to write for example?

Comment: @Mad Physicist I think I figured it out, I wasn't sure how to define the subfield as Data.(field{1}) ... Not the best coding style, but it works.

Comment: Please edit your question. All relevant information should be in there without having to read the comments. You could use the comments to notify me after,  but not to hold the actual content.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab like matrices Bensa.... You should drop your approach **now**.

**Fixed size datasets**

If all `a`, `b`, `c` arrays are `10x1` sized, you should switch immediately to a **cell of arrays**, being the index the durations, and the arrays columns the datasets for each duration:

```
a: [1x1 cell]
    a{1}: [10xna double]
    a{2}: [10xnb double]
    a{3}: [10xnc double]
```

All statistics go easy. You have two `for` loops, one for the durations, other for the dataset. Matlab vectorizes the functions inside each dataset (most of the time). In here, i am assuming `max(.)` is your aggregation array function for obtaining statistics:

```
n=length(a);
for i=1:n
    ni=size(a{i},2);
    for j=1:ni
        max(a{i})
        mean(a{i}')'
        if j==j0 && i==i0
            a{i}(:,j)=[];  % Cleanup j0th event in i0th dataset
        end
    end
end
```

Do you need to compare `a.a1` & `b.b1` & `c.c1`? If that is true, then you forcedly should create the auxiliar array `x`, and then get your stats:

```
for i=1:n
    x(:,i)=a{i};
end
max(x')'
```

**Variable size datasets**

If the `a`, `b`, `c` arrays are different each time, then you upgrade the last data and switch to a **cell of cells**:

```
a{1}: [1xna cell]
    a{1,1}: [la(1)x1 double]
    ...
    a{1,na}: [la(na)x1 double]
a{2}: [1xnb cell]
    ...
a{3}: [1xnc cell]
    ...
```

In here the `max(.')'` approach is useless, because every dataset could be of different length. If that is the case, you still can reference the data as usually through columns:

```
n=length(a);
for i=1:n
    ni(i)=size(a{i},2);
    for j=1:ni(i)
        li=length(a{i,j})   % Length of each dataset
        max(a{i,j})
        % mean(a{i}')'      % This do not work anymore
        if j==j0 && i==i0
            a{i,j}=[];      % Cleanup j0th event in i0th dataset
        end
    end
end
```

Do this make sense?. Feel free to comment below...